# How can I count the number of structures inside my file ? c++, files

Tags: c++, file, struct

```cpp
struct Product{
    int price;
};

int main()
{
    // I am dynamically allocating n structures 
    int n; cin >> n;
    Product* p;
    p = new Product[n];

    // I give each one of them a price
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> p[i].price;
    }

    // Then, I store the structures in a file
    fstream file;
    file.open("file.bat", ios::app);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p), n * sizeof(Product));
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Assuming each time I reopen the program, I will **append** new products to the file, how can I know how many structures (products) I have stored inside the file in total?

Comment: Just to point you towards info: google std::vector and serialization. vector will allow you to dynamically grow memory at runtime. Serialization will explain how to save/load data.

Comment: Either divide the file size by `sizeof(Product)`, or store an additional size value in the file header.

Comment: `std::vector` is the better solution here. There are very few good reasons to manually manage heap memory (especially in 2021) -- and this is not one of them. `vector` makes this easy, quick, can be reserved up-front, and more safe than manually allocating yourself. Plus if you do this, it carries along the `size()` with it as well -- which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps (I'm beginner) ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct product { int price; };

inline auto& operator>>(std::istream& stream, product& object) { return stream >> object.price; }


template <typename _Type>
inline auto& write_file(std::ostream& stream, const _Type& object, const std::streamsize count = 1) {

    const auto raw = static_cast<const void*>(&object);

    return stream.write(static_cast<const char*>(raw), count * sizeof(_Type));

}
template <typename _Type>
inline auto& read_file(std::istream& stream,        _Type& object, const std::streamsize count = 1) {

    const auto raw = static_cast<void*>(&object);

    return stream.read(static_cast<char*>(raw), count * sizeof(_Type));

}


int main()
{

    /*
    
     1. Always initialize.
     2. Use "using namespace std;" carefully.
     3. Manage all your resources (memory included).
     4. Check more operations (including readings).

    */

    size_t values_size{};

    if ((std::cin >> values_size).fail() || values_size == 0) return 1;


    const auto values = std::make_unique<product[]>(values_size); // Personally, i prefer use vector<product>

    for (auto it = values.get(); it != values.get() + values_size; ++it) {

        auto& value = *it;
        std::cin >> value;

    }


    constexpr auto file_name = "file.bat";
   
    {

        std::ofstream file(file_name, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::app);

        if (!file.is_open()) return 1;

        write_file(file, *values.get(), values_size);

    }


    size_t count{};

    {

        std::ifstream file(file_name, std::ios_base::binary);

        if (!file.is_open()) return 1;

        do {

            decltype(values)::element_type value{};
            if (read_file(file, value)) ++count;

        } while (file);


    }

    std::cout << "Number of products inside the file " << file_name << " : " << count << '\n';

}
```

Edit : (Vector version)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct product { int price; };

inline auto& operator>>(std::istream& stream, product& object) { return stream >> object.price; }


template <typename _Type>
inline auto& write_file(std::ostream& stream, const _Type& object, const std::streamsize count = 1) {

    const auto raw = static_cast<const void*>(&object);

    return stream.write(static_cast<const char*>(raw), count * sizeof(_Type));

}
template <typename _Type>
inline auto& read_file(std::istream& stream, _Type& object, const std::streamsize count = 1) {

    const auto raw = static_cast<void*>(&object);

    return stream.read(static_cast<char*>(raw), count * sizeof(_Type));

}


template <typename _Type>
auto fill_vector(std::istream& stream, std::vector<_Type>& vector) {

    do {

        _Type elem{};

        if (stream >> elem) vector.emplace_back(std::move(elem));

    } while (stream && vector.size() < vector.capacity());

}

int main()
{

    /*

     1. Always initialize.
     2. Use "using namespace std;" carefully.
     3. Manage all your resources (memory included).
     4. Check more operations (including readings).

    */
 
    std::vector<product> values;
    {

        size_t n{};

        if ((std::cin >> n).fail() || n == 0) return 1;

        values.reserve(n);

        fill_vector(std::cin, values);

    }


    constexpr auto file_name = "file.bin";

    {

        std::ofstream file(file_name, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::app);

        if (!file.is_open()) return 1;

        write_file(file, *values.data(), values.size());

    }


    size_t count{};

    {

        std::ifstream file(file_name, std::ios_base::binary);

        if (!file.is_open()) return 1;

        do {

            decltype(values)::value_type value{};
            if (read_file(file, value)) ++count;

        } while (file);


    }

    std::cout << "Number of products inside the file " << file_name << " : " << count << '\n';

}
```

The write_file and read_file functions work in the same way as using naked reinterpret_cast, the difference is that they take care of the conversions for you and guarantee the writing/reading of 1 or n elements of a given type without specifying the dimension of the type, this allows you to avoid writing/reading of sliced objects or merged objects.

fill_vector creates and reads a new _Type element, if the reading was successful, the element will be added to the vector, otherwise the element will not be added. The loop will stop if a reading has not been successful or if the vector is full.

std::move serves to "activate" the move semantics, instead of creating a copy of elem within the vector, we move it, this can be useful and efficient for owner objects.

To count the amount of products within the file, I created a loop that reads objects that have the size of a product. If we can read a product, the count value will start to increase.

Comment: Please don't just dump a bag of code on the readers. At a minimum, explain the general strategy that your code uses.

Comment: Sorry. Is it better this way?

Comment: Well, better, but only marginally, because you only repeat what can be seen in the code. I was thinking of the grand picture, the idea behind the code you wrote, such as: "To read back a file, you either look at the files size to measure how many items there are, or you read items of known size one by one (and push them into a vector if you want to keep them) until end-of-file is reported."